# Retrieve the current platform in SauceLabs

Tags: jasmine, protractor, saucelabs

I'm trying to write my custom Jasmine reporter for my Protractor tests running on SauceLabs.

I can easily get the current browser using `browser.getCapabilities()` but how can I get the platform?

```js
var multiCapabilities = [
    {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'platform': 'Windows 7',
    },
    {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'platform': 'Linux',
    }
];

exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    onPrepare: function () {
        browser.getCapabilities().then(function (capabilities) {
            var browserName = capabilities.caps_.browserName
            var browserVersion = capabilities.caps_.version

            // How can I get the full platform here??? i.e OS name + version
        })
    }
};
```

Thanks!

Comment: `capabilities.caps_.platform`? I see we use it to determine the platform - does it work for you?

Comment: It just gives me the following information: **XP** when I'm on Windows, **MAC** when I'm on Mac OSX, and something else when I'm on Linux. I need the OS version also, since I can test on Windows 7, 8, 10 etc... Basically the best would be to retrieve what I provide in my capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the value you are looking for:

```
  browser.getProcessedConfig().then(function (config) {
        var platformName = config.capabilities.platform;
      });
```

All of the capabilities are available with this method, so you could use browser.getProcessedConfig() for the browserName and browserVersion as well.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for! Actually I figured it out myself just a few hours before your answer :D